# 10X low rate of correct barcodes was observed for the candidate chemistry choices for the input

Tags: single-cell, fastq

I am testing a 10x fastq dataset , but cellranger count complains "An extremely low rate of correct barcodes was observed for all the candidate chemistry choices for the input", I have tried all the chemistry recommendation codes on the 10x genomics website, and I still get the same result, how can I solve this problem, thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer when the question does not include what the input is, what command was run, ... I can only suggest to use the `--chemistry=auto` option of `cellranger count`.

Comment: What does the quality look like on those reads?  If this is 10XGenomics library, they should be able to help your troubleshoot.

Comment: Could you please give a few more details about the nature of this project? Are you sure this is a single-cell dataset (I'm aware that 10X do other non-single-cell things as well)? Showing the first few lines of header from the fastq files can be very helpful to work out the structure of the experiment.

Comment: how were your fastqs generated? and how are they named?

Comment: Thanks @ciwei for providing your answer. Could you kindly check the "accept" box for your answer? This does help site statistics

Answer (score 2):

I have solve this problem, cause the combined barcode is differernt from the common 10x barcode. when mapping the genome, need to add-- chemistry ARC-v1 when cellranger count.

Comment: Excuse me, how do you determine the required chemistry?

Comment: ARC-v1 means this was done using a multiomic kit. From `cellranger count --help` "To analyze the GEX portion of multiome data, chemistry must be set to 'ARC-v1'; 'ARC-v1' chemistry cannot be autodetected"

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @maximilian-press, converted from comments:

> I can't comment on 10X data specifically, however, I suggest writing a
> simple script or command that counts the frequency of each barcode,
> and reports back the N (10? 20? 100?) most frequent ones, which will
> allow you to investigate in more detail. This is what I have done in
> the case of suspected bardode swaps or reverse complement issues.